# Finding order and cosets of subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For:

> Let $P$ be the pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in \Bbb Z_4$, and $b \in \Bbb Z_2$
>
> An operation, $*$, is defined by: $$(a,b)*(c,d)=(a+c  \pmod 4, b+d \pmod 2)$$ for all $(a,c),(b,d)\in P$
>
> H = ⟨(1,1)⟩ is the cyclical subgroup generated by (1,1)

How do I find the order of $H$ and the cosets of $H$?

Comment: Hint:$$|H|=|(1,1)|=\operatorname{lcm}(|1_4|,|1_2|) $$

Comment: I suggest you add some thoughts on the problem lest it is closed as off-topic, @woddal :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Here $1_4$ is a generator of $(\Bbb Z_4, +_4)$ and $1_2$ is a generator of $(\Bbb Z_2, +_2)$.

*For a further hint, click, hover over, or tap the box below.*

> Since $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2$ has only eight elements, it is feasible & practical to simply compute all the powers of $(1_4,1_2)$.

Another hint:

> Use Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Would $4$ be the correct order as $H$<sup>$4$</sup> is $(0,0)$? Would the cosets be each element multiplied by (1,1) or are there more cosets?

Comment: Yes, indeed, $4(1_4, 1_2)=(4\times 1_4, 4\times 1_2)=(0_4, 0_2)$, @woddal.

Comment: Does that help, @woddal?

Comment: Does this mean that there is only 1 coset since the number of cosets is |G|/|H|?

Comment: The other coset is $(1_4, 0_2)+H$, @woddal.